# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'swag_advanced_cart_cookie_name_hash' in 'field list' in

Tags: shopware

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'swag_advanced_cart_cookie_name_hash' in 'field list' in

....

This error is occurring after registration a customer.

Shopware version is 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column `swag_advanced_cart_cookie_name_hash` comes from the Advanced Cart plugin and should be created when the plugin was installed. Try to reinstall the plugin.